# Are all modern browsers implementing a remember password feature?

Tags: html, passwords, browser, remember-me

Are all modern browsers implementing a remember password feature? Or do I have to implement it via cookies for some browsers? I am thinking about Opera, FireFox, IE, Chrome, Safari, etc...

I mean, when you login on a website (for example), Firefox offers to remember the entered password with the provided user login id. Later, the user does not have to retype it anymore.

**EDIT**

To be more precise, I am referring indeed to form fields such as HTML passwords etc...

Comment: Remembering password != "remember me."

Comment: All of the browsers you mention have the facility to save and auto-populate form fields (including username/password fields)

Comment: @Clive Thanks. If you create a solution, I'll approve it.

Comment: @Downvoters Can you comment on your down votes?

Comment: @Matt Yes, I know. That's why I have specifically mentioned passwords in the question (I know I would have to protect the cookie etc...)

Comment: @JVerstry: No problem, I've added an answer as you suggested :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the browsers you mention have the facility to save and auto-populate form fields (including username/password fields)